how to calclate the fee of a segwit transaction?
I am using bitcoin-js to construct a PSBT transaction.
Suppose address A has 10 UTXOs, each containing 0.0001 BTC.
Now I want to construct a transaction to send 0.0005 BTC to address B.
If I use 5 of the UTXOs, there will be no BTC left to pay the fee.
If I use 6 UTXOs, the transaction will succeed when the fee is less than 0.0001 BTC, but will fail when the fee is greater than 0.0001 BTC.
Similarly, using 7 or more UTXOs also encounters the same issue.
How can I calculate the fee and the required number of UTXOs to ensure the transaction succeeds and to calculate the change? Thank you.
